# apply function to dataframe's chosen column whilst grouping by another chosen column

Tags: r

I would like to apply the below function (`cut.at.n.tile`) to a data frame (`some_data_frame`) whilst grouping by a chosen column (e.g. `SomeGroupingColumn`) and choosing the target column (e.g. `ChosenColumn`). I tried using `sapply()` without success - see code below. Any input very much appreciated. Apologies for this not being fully replicable/self contained ...

```
cut.at.n.tile <- function(X, n = 7) { 
   cut(X, breaks = quantile(X, probs = (0:n)/n, na.rm = TRUE),
       labels = 1:n, include.lowest = TRUE)
}

some_data_frame$SeasonTypeNumber = sapply(split(some_data_frame['ChosenColumn'], SomeGroupingColumn), cut.at.n.tile)
```

Comment: Your function is applied to a vector. `some_data_frame['ChosenColumn']` is still a dataframe, not a vector. You should use double brackets to extract `'ChosenColumn'` as a vector, i.e. `some_data_frame[['ChosenColumn']]`

Comment: you know what I may actually mixed up Python and R here ... sorry it has been a long day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1. `some_data_frame['ChosenColumn']` always returns a single-column `data.frame`, not a vector which your function requires. I suggest switching to `some_data_frame[['ChosenColumn']]`.
2. `SomeGroupingColumn` looks like it should be a column (hence the name) in the data, but it is not referenced within a frame. Perhaps `some_data_frame[['SomeGroupingColumn']]`.
3. You need to ensure that the `breaks=` used are unique. For example,

   ```r
   cut.at.n.tile(subset(mtcars, cyl == 8)$disp)
   # Error in cut.default(X, breaks = quantile(X, probs = (0:n)/n, na.rm = TRUE),  : 
   #   'breaks' are not unique
   ```

   If we debug that function, we see

   ```r
   X
   #  [1] 360.0 360.0 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0 351.0 301.0
   quantile(X, probs = (0:n)/n, na.rm = TRUE)
   #        0% 14.28571% 28.57143% 42.85714% 57.14286% 71.42857% 85.71429%      100% 
   #  275.8000  275.8000  303.1429  336.2857  354.8571  371.4286  442.8571  472.0000
   ```

   where `275.8` is repeated. This can happen based on nuances in the raw data, and you can't really predict when it will occur.

   Since we'll likely have multiple groups, all of the subvectors' `levels=` (since `cut` returns a `factor`) must be the same length, though admittedly `1` in one group is unlikely to be the same as `1` in another group.

   Since in this case we can never be certain which n-tile a number *strictly* applies (in `275.8` in the first or second n-tile?), we can only adjust one of the dupes and accept the imperfection. I suggest a `cumsum(duplicated(.)*1e-9)`: the premise is that it adds an iota to each value that is a dupe, rendering it no-longer a dupe. It is possible that adding `1e-9` to one value will make it a dupe of the next ... so we can be a little OCD by repeatedly doing this until we have no duplicates.
4. `sapply` is unlikely to return a vector, much (almost "certainly") more likely to return a `list` (if the groups are not perfectly balanced) or a `matrix` (perfectly balanced). We cannot simply `unlist`, since the order of the unlisted vectors will likely not be the order of the source data.
   We can use `` `split<-` ``, or we can use a few other techniques (`dplyr` and/or `data.table`)

Updated function, and demonstration with `mtcars`:

```r
cut.at.n.tile <- function(X, n = 7) { 
   brks <- quantile(X, probs = (0:n)/n, na.rm = TRUE)
   while (any(dupes <- duplicated(brks))) brks <- brks + cumsum(1e-9*dupes)
   cut(X, breaks = brks, labels = 1:n, include.lowest = TRUE)
}
```

## base R

```r
ret <- lapply(split(mtcars[['disp']], mtcars[['cyl']]), cut.at.n.tile)
mtcars[["newcol"]] <- NA  # create an empty column
split(mtcars[['newcol']], mtcars[['cyl']]) <- ret
mtcars
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newcol
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      2
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      2
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      4
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      7
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      5
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      6
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4      5
# Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      7
# Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2      7
# Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4      4
# Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4      4
# Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3      1
# Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3      1
# Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3      1
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4      7
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4      7
# Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4      6
# Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1      2
# Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2      1
# Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1      1
# Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1      5
# Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2      3
# AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2      3
# Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4      4
# Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2      6
# Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1      3
# Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2      5
# Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2      3
# Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      4
# Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6      1
# Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8      2
# Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2      6
```

Validation:

```r
cut.at.n.tile(subset(mtcars, cyl == 8)$disp)
#  [1] 5 5 1 1 1 7 7 6 3 3 4 6 4 2
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
subset(mtcars, cyl == 8)$newcol
#  [1] 5 5 1 1 1 7 7 6 3 3 4 6 4 2
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(newcol = cut.at.n.tile(disp)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 32 × 12
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb newcol
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> 
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 2     
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 2     
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 4     
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 7     
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 5     
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 6     
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 5     
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 7     
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 7     
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 4     
# # … with 22 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, newcol := cut.at.n.tile(disp), by = .(cyl)][]
#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb newcol
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <fctr>
#  1:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4      2
#  2:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4      2
#  3:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1      4
#  4:  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1      7
#  5:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2      5
#  6:  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1      6
#  7:  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4      5
#  8:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2      7
#  9:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2      7
# 10:  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0     4     4      4
# ---                                                                         
# 23:  15.2     8 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2      3
# 24:  13.3     8 350.0   245  3.73 3.840 15.41     0     0     3     4      4
# 25:  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2      6
# 26:  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1      3
# 27:  26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2      5
# 28:  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2      3
# 29:  15.8     8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4      4
# 30:  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6      1
# 31:  15.0     8 301.0   335  3.54 3.570 14.60     0     1     5     8      2
# 32:  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2      6
```

Comment: I can't see your proposed change in the first point (**some_data_frame['ChosenColumn']** always returns a single-column data.frame, not a vector which your function requires. I suggest switching to **some_data_frame['ChosenColumn']**)

Comment: See `split(mtcars[['disp']], ...`, that is where the `[[` goes. I'm not going to switch to `some_data_frame['ChosenColumn']`, it errors with `'x' must be numeric`. Have you tried it and somehow got it to work with the single-`[`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, did that answer your question?

Comment: It's more clear now. I think you've a typo in your answer. The proposed code is the same as current one.